# calculating Pi different ways

Tags: algorithm, math, trigonometry, pi, approximation

I know two ways of calculating pi in code.  Either

`pi = 4.0 * atan(1.0)`

or

`pi = acos(-1.0)`

What is the benefit of one vs. the other?  I know there are some languages that have a built in pi representation, but this is not asking about them.  Also, are there any other common ways of calculating pi as well as how they compare to others?

Comment: what are you trying to compare? Accuracy? Speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the benefit of one vs. the other?

These functions were not designed only to approximate the value of π. In its case, I see no significant speed.

As a matter of fact, I did a [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) experiment on my system, where I see the same approximated value of pi with both functions, and the same speed, more or less.

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 atan.cpp
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out 
It took me on average 1.69e-13 seconds.
3.14159265358979312
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 acos.cpp
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out 
It took me on average 1.7e-13 seconds.
3.14159265358979312
```

The code computes π in a loop, and adds the loop's counter to it, making sure that the compiler won't optimize that away (same value at every iteration):

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ cat acos.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <ratio>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>

#define ITER 1000000

int main ()
{
  using namespace std::chrono;

  high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

  for(int i = 0; i < ITER; ++i)
  {
    auto pi = acos(-1.0) + i;
    pi += i + i;
  } 
  high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();

  duration<double> time_span = duration_cast<duration<double>>(t2 - t1);

  std::cout << "It took me on average " << time_span.count()/(double)ITER << " seconds.";
  std::cout << std::endl;
  auto pi = acos(-1.0);
  std::cout.precision(std::numeric_limits< double >::max_digits10);
  std::cout << std::fixed << pi << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

based on my [Time measurements (C++)](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/1651-2/). The `atan()` code is the same, just the function changes.

> Also, are there any other common ways of calculating pi as well as how they compare to others?

There are many other ways of approximating π and comparing them all is just *too broad*. For example, Plato has approximated π like [this](https://divisbyzero.com/2012/06/20/platos-approximation-of-pi/).

Comment: The Indiana state legislature decided to approximate pi as 3.2: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_Pi_Bill

Comment: FTR, your wording looks wrong to me. These "functions" were not "designed" to "approximate" the value of Pi. In math sense, values of both `acos(-1)` and `4 * atan(1)` **are** Pi, also coincidentally being equal. The same might be said about `2 * asin(1)` and many other expressions.

Comment: @duffymo interesting, hadn't heard of it! iehrlich, I said not only. However, I am afraid I am that I might be a victim of the poorness of English.